# How to notify main activity after service is complete?

Tags: android

I have a service that is retrieving URL's from a remote server for a MainActivity that i launch at the beginning of the project.

The problem is, i need these URL's before the Activity its ran.

The service is launched when the activity is started for the first time.

I put the URL's in the sharedpreference once they are retrieved.

But by the time this happens the activity has already loaded the default images.
I am using an Adapter to LazyLoad the images.

How can i notify the activity to refresh it self or refresh the BaseAdapter i am using to download the images once the service is finished?

Any better idea's are welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to update the `Activity` from the `Service`, you should look into [BroadcastReceivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

A googled tutorial can be found [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html).

Comment: I know plenty about broadcast receivers. In fact, i use one to launch my service after a Alarm goes off to launch it. How will this be beneficial?

Comment: Once the URLs are retrieved from the service, send a broadcast with the URL stored as an extra.  You could send a broadcast for each image URL that is grabbed from the server, that way you could even load the images as they're downloaded instead of waiting for them all to complete. Your Service will be the one to send the broadcasts and your Activity will be the one with the receiver.

Comment: Could you give me a code example of a implementation of what your suggesting?

Comment: This is going to run into a problem though. Say your activity starts the service, and then while the service is running the activity is paused (e.g. the user goes back to the home screen). Before the activity is resumed, the service completes and the broadcasts it's results. Once the activity is resumed, it now has no way of obtaining the results because the broadcast has already been sent out. It will be forced to call start the service again and repeat the whole process.

Comment: @Kurtis, If the URLs are going to be stored in the SharedPreferences, this shouldn't be a problem at all... when the Activity starts, it'll check the SharedPreferences for the URLs, and if there's an update from the service, it'll be notified from the service. The service is capable of altering the Shared Preferences, so just check them in onResume().

Comment: @user856377, the tutorial link I posted in the answer has a full example of implementing a service sending broadcasts to an Activity's BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @John Ah, yes. I missed the part about them being stored in shared preferences. Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the new Loader classes. They're friggen awesome.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html. You can use the Backwards Compatibility package if you're developing for an api level less than 11. http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html

Comment: Whats the link to the AsyncTaskLoader>

Comment: Use ViewModels for lifecycle downloads.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is get rid of using a `Service` for downloading your image URLs. Instead just do this on a background thread using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You can keep a handle to your `ImageView` in each `AsyncTask`, and when the image is done downloading you can set the image in onPostExecute.

Comment: Ive went with this method before. The only problem is, since i will be saving the images in cache i dont want the URL's to take up time and be ran every time the activity is opened. Thus, i ran a service because the URL's will change every weekend, and that is when i want the URL's to be retrieved. The issue with this is. Initially the activity starts without having any images loaded because it doesnt have URLs yet. Second problem is i have no way of notifying the activity when the service is finished and to refresh to get the images in the adapter.

Comment: Is the cache in memory, or on disk? I suggest you save the images to files once they've been downloaded. You can check for them on disk before they are downloaded, and you won't incur that much latency. Using a Service is overkill, and much more complicated than you need here. I don't suggest messing with BroadcastReceivers, it will only further complicate an otherwise easy task.